# The for loop doesn't iterate

Tags: matlab, for-loop

In MATLAB the following `for` loop:

```
for i = [1:100]' 
    %'// Do something, such as disp(i)
end
```

isn't apparently really implemented by iteration, rather `i` becomes the matrix [1 2 3 ... 100] and the "loop" is only executed once on this matrix `i`. You can verify this by printing the value of `i` or other tracking information. Only a single pass is made through the loop.

Is it possible to force MATLAB to do genuine looping? The reason I ask is that the above approach is fine for many cases but much more painful when you have nested loops that need to run.

**Example**:
The following code won't do what you would expect if you thought you were getting actual iteration over a loop:

```
for i = outlier
    data(i) = median(data(i-100:i+100))
end
```

One would expect at each outlier index this would replace data(i) with the median of the data from i-100 to i+100, but it doesn't. In fact, the median returns a single value computed on a conglomerate of all the ranges you cared about, and every data(i) point is replaced with that single value.

Comment: Can you post output that reproduces what you're seeing.  I have not seen this behavior, and I have paid a lot of attention to for loops in Matlab.

Comment: Don't you mean `median(data(i-100:i+100))` ? (with a ':')

Comment: @Clement J. Yes I do. Corrected now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you write

```
for i = (1:100)' %'# square brackets would work as well
   doSomething
end
```

the loop is executed only once, since a `for`-loop iterates over all *columns* of whatever is to the right of the equal sign (it would iterate 200 times with a 100-by-200 array to the right of the equal sign).

However, in your example, you have `i=[1:100]`, which evaluates to a row vector. Thus, the loop should execute 100x.

If you iterate over an array that might be `nx1` instead of `1xn`, you can, for safety reasons, write:

```
for i = myArray(:)'  %'# guarantee nx1, then transpose to 1xn
end
```

Comment: +1. Except for last paragraph: the `i=[1:100]` loop (like in OP's pseudocode) executes 100 times, not once.

Answer (score 7):

This is not correct. The code:

```
for i=1:100
    disp(i)
end
```

will print all the values 1 through 100 consecutively. While Matlab does encourage vectorization, you can definitely use traditional loops with the style of coding you used above.

Comment: +1 Better answer.  :)  I have never seen the behavior described by the OP, and I pay rather close attention to iterations (note the username...).  I'm not sure what may be behind the reported behavior.

Comment: His `outlier` variable may be a column vector. Matlab `for` loops iterate through the columns of something, not the elements. For row vectors like [1:100] it's the same thing; but `for i = [1:100]'` will do a single pass.

Comment: @Iterator: The behavior occurrs if the array is nx1 instead of 1xn.

Comment: @AndrewJanke - Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I was answering the question as posted, but that's a very good point to be aware of.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for the clarification.  I vaguely remember doing that.  I suppose I got that out of my system, and you've demonstrated why one should be careful about this.  Good insight.